# Bind Textbox to specific row/column of a datatable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datatable

I have a strongly type Dataset containing a DataTable with a static number of rows. I am trying to bind individual labels and textboxes to certain row/column combinations in the datatable. When I bind directly to the dataTable the textbox does not update. I have tried binding through a CollectionViewSource, but that not only doesn't update, it also doesn't allow me to select the row of the data to which I am trying to bind. What is the best way to bind a textbox to a specific row and column of a DataTable? Specifically I am looking for what I should specify in the XAML as the Source and Path.

Answer (score 2):

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding YourTable.Rows[1][ColumnName]}"/>
```

Comment: How would I access my table in XAML? It is created in another part of the program. I can gain access to it in the code behind, but if I try to access it like that in the XAML it cannot resolve the symbol.

Comment: Post your code and XAML so I can understand better what you have

Comment: The code I am working on is proprietary and cannot be posted (not to mention on a computer not connected to the internet)

Comment: wtf? how much secret black magic can a simple DataTable have? pff no one is going to help you any further if you don't show what the code looks like. Otherwise make a fake version of it just as an example