# How can I bind a control to a specific cell of a DataTable instead of a specific column in the active row?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a form with a matrix of textboxes for entering numbers. While it would certainly simplify things to just use a DataGridView, I've been told that's not an option.

We normally bind to a DataTable in a DataSet. With 15 rows and 5 columns, that's *75 columns* I would need to add to the DataTable the form's controls bind to. What I would like to do is make a separate DataTable in the DataSet for these controls, give it 15 DataRows & 5 DataColumns and just have each control bind to the appropriate row & column of the DataTable.

Unfortunately, I don't see any way to bind to a specific *cell*; I can only bind controls to a specific *column* in the DataTable and then it uses whatever the "active" row is. Am I missing something or is this really not possible?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14369071/bind-textbox-to-specific-row-column-of-a-datatable) seems to suggest it's doable in XAML (which we're not using) and should therefore theoretically be doable in C# (either through Visual Studio's Form Designer or programmatically).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307584/c-sharp-binding-on-specific-row-in-table/1307700#1307700) to another question (assuming I'm reading it properly) suggests it can be done somehow with a BindingSource, but it's not clear how. The BindingSource won't let me bind it to a specific DataTable in a DataSet, only the DataSet itself (to clarify: I am *not* having any trouble getting *controls* to bind to DataTables), and I can't seem to get a control to bind to the BindingSource. Am I doing something wrong?

Edit: To clarify, I'm looking for a two-way binding, where any change to the control updates the bound cell and any change to the bound cell updates the control.

Comment: Just an fyi, a column and row, can be referred to as a cell.  So you're looking to bind the textboxes to individual cells of the datatable.

Comment: @Khan Good catch, since I couldn't use a DataGridView I wasn't thinking in terms of cells, but yes, a cell is what I want to bind to.

Comment: Maybe use unbound controls and write code to load/save the control values to the datatable?

Comment: @rheitzman We're trying to keep all our forms consistent; controls bind to a DataTable, any events are triggered by changes to that DataTable, and saving/loading to/from the database is done by copying to/from the DataTable. I'd be told to spend the next several hours adding 75 columns to the normal DataTable rather than get permission to access the controls directly.

Comment: FYI: I'm sure you can bind to a specific DataTable in a DataSet.

Comment: @Lizzie I can get *controls* to bind to a specific DataTable just fine. It's the *BindingSource* object mentioned in the second question I linked that won't seem to bind to a specific DataTable.

Comment: Fwiw, the answer in the second link doesn't provide what you think it does: it still binds to a column, but it filters the datasource to only contain the desired row.

Comment: I believe a solution could come from something like `new Binding("Text", dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][0], "...")`, but unfortunately `DataRow`s' `ItemArray`s contain plain `object`s with no usable properties for such a binding...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, in fact you can use some `event` of the `DataTable` to bind data here. The events I want to mention here are `ColumnChanged`. The event handler of this event can get the `Column` and `Row` of the cell which has something changed via the 2nd argument passed in. Here is the code for you:

```
    //This is just a demo without check for valid cell (with RowIndex and ColumnIndex in range)
    public class CustomDataTable : DataTable
    {
        public Dictionary<Cell, Control> CellBindings { get; private set; }
        public CustomDataTable()
        {
            CellBindings = new Dictionary<Cell, Control>();
        }
        protected override void OnColumnChanged(DataColumnChangeEventArgs e)
        {                
            Cell cell = new Cell {RowIndex = Rows.IndexOf(e.Row), ColumnIndex = e.Column.Ordinal};
            Control c;
            if (CellBindings.TryGetValue(cell, out c))
            {
                c.Text = e.Row[e.Column].ToString();
            }
            base.OnColumnChanged(e);
        }
        public struct Cell
        {
            public int RowIndex { get; set; }
            public int ColumnIndex { get; set; }
            public Cell(int rowIndex, int colIndex) : this()
            {
                RowIndex = rowIndex;
                ColumnIndex = colIndex;
            }
        }
    }
    //Use it
    //Bind cell at (2,0) to the textBox1
    customDataTable.CellBindings.Add(new CustomDataTable.Cell(2, 0), textBox1);
```

**NOTE**: The code is just for **One-way binding**, from `DataTable` to the `Control`. If you want **Two-way binding**, **we have to add much more code**. I don't have time digging into this problem. But I would like to share the idea to achieve it. The way binding from `DataTable` to `Control` is already demonstrated as above but the way binding from `Control` to `DataTable` can be done via the `DataBindings` of the `Control` or some **event** notifying changes such as `TextChanged`.

Comment: I'm looking for a two-way binding but this seems like it's worth investigating.

Comment: @ObliviousSage yes, as I pointed out for how to achieve the other way. I'm sure it's **feasible**. I also think this is the only way, you have to write your own code. There is no **already easy way** to bind cell to control as you want. In fact, **DataGridView** has the same internal implementation to bind cell to control (each control here can be considered as `DataGridViewCell`).